# Video Editing: What is the diff. between Sequence Render Animation & Render Animation?

Tags: rendering, edit-mode, video-sequence-editor, video, timeline

Good day,

I started using Blender v2.82a a week ago exclusively for Video Editing. I have seen a few tutorials but the following query has not been addressed yet.

Aside from being faster and allowing renders to happen between a Temporary Preview window, are there other other differences between "Render Animation" from the top menu bar and the "Sequence Render Animation" from the Sequencer menu? So far I have been exclusively using Render Animation in fear that it might produce superior quality at the cost of long render times (I use perceptually lossless @Slowest speed, MPEG4 container w/H.264 codec).

Comment: Done. Thank you.

Comment: If you found an answer to your question, you can answer it yourself, so others searching for an answer on the same question, will benefit from it.